# am trying to build a simple quotes generator that will enable the user to click generate and it will display randomly with a timer

Tags: javascript

```
var cars = ["camry", "corolla", "toyota", "honda", "ford", "bmw", "audi", "mercedes", "volkswagen", "tesla", "lamborghini"];

var x = 30;

var gen = setInterval(function generate() {
  var text = document.getElementById("child-box");
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length);
  text.innerHTML = cars[random];
  var time = document.getElementById("timing").innerText = --x;

  if (x == 0) {
    clearInterval(gen);
  }
}, 1000);

function gen() {
  generate();
  document.getElementById("clicked").addEventListener('click', generate);
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Is there a problem with the code? Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length);` you might get index outbound (in js it would simply return undefined, on others you may get exceptions) this way, try using modulo (`%`) instead of multiplication. something like `Math.floor(Math.random()) % cars.Length` will do.

Comment: @BagusTesa that just produces zeros

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze you are right, i forgot `Math.random()` returns number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.